# dynamically create li in ui with given data and class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to create li dynamically under an ui of id "dynamicData" and with list of objects having field :rule_id ,rule_set_name ,last_updated_timeStamp.

These values i have marked as double braces in below example.

Li format :

```
<li><input type="checkbox" class="left select-all" value=”{{ rule_id }}”>
 <h3>{{ rule_set_name }}</h3><input type=”hidden” value=”{{ last_updated_timeStamp }}”>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>
```

but i am not able to add all fields.

can somebody help me with this.

Comment: look at a templating engine

Comment: BTW, don't use fancy quotes in HTML.

Comment: Why aren't you able to add all the fields? Please show the code you wrote that tries, and someone should be able to show how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java script for this with a loop:

```
for (var i=0;i<rule_id.length;i++)
{
document.write("<li>" + rule_id[i] + "</li>");
}
```

Comment: thanks. actually finally i did this way only. made string of all li's and used handlebars. quite easily done.